# В js создать тег

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который изменяет цену при передвижении ползунка. Как в скрипте прописать чтобы цена, которая сейчас выводиться в span, записывалась еще в отдельный какой-то тег (например p)? Хочу уменьшить размер шрифта, но если сейчас уменьшать у спана, уменьшаются и кругляшки

```
{literal}
<script>
    $(function() {
        changeNumbers();
    });
   function changeNumbers()
   {
      var iteration = 0;
        $('span.ui-slider-handle').each(function() {
            if(iteration == 0)
                $(this).html($("#minCurr").val());
            else
                $(this).html($("#maxCurr").val());
            iteration++;
        });
   } 
</script>
{/literal}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="price-range ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="slider">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 97.6988%;"></div>
    <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 0%;">26801</span>
    <span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 97.6988%;">33891</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$(this).html('<span class="small">' + $("#minCurr").val() + '</span>');
```